# Unbind "click" for "onclick" attribute

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, javascript

I have the following html element:

```
<span class="btn btn-mini btn-primary row-remove" onclick="someFunction(param1, param2)">
   <i>Remove</i>
</span>
```

When I do something else, I am disabling those buttons on the page:

```
$(".row-remove").attr("disabled", true);
```

The issue is, if you click the disabled button it still fires the "onclick", which is causing a big issue (there's a reason the buttons are disabled).

Is there any way to "disable" the onclick event as well? I've tried unbinding "click" but as excepted it didn't work (it's onclick, not bind()).

Thanks.

Best, Gary

Comment: PLease make sure about the element, is this a class ? If so you can Inspect your element and then click on remove button, you will see that the attribute **disabled** will appear into **row-remove** class element.
You can try with **$(".row-remove").attr("disabled", "disabled");** (I'm not sure both are work same for me).
This is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only form elements can have the `disabled` attribute. Toggling a click event on and off can get complicated. I would suggest that you add a `data` attribute to the element to show the elements' state. Something like this:

```
$('.row-remove').data('disabled', true);

function someFunction(param1, param2) {
    if (!$('.row-remove').data('disabled')) {
        // element is not disabled, continue on...
    }
}
```

I would also suggest attaching the click event using javascript to maintain a better separation of concerns:

```
<span class="btn btn-mini btn-primary row-remove" data-param1="param1" data-param2="param2">
   <i>Remove</i>
</span>
```

```js
$('row-remove').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var param1 = $el.data('param1'); // = 'param1'
    var param2 = $el.data('param2'); // = 'param2'

    if (!$el.data('disabled')) {
        // element is not disabled, continue on...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great! Regarding your suggestion, I chose onclick because the backbone template I am using attaches this onclick event based on conditions and creates the param1 and param2 from the model.
I wasn't actually aware of "data-param1=..", this is VERY useful, thank you. I will update my code with this now, it's much much cleaner =)